# Check Constraints in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I want not to allow my DB user to enter bigger dates than `2017-03-18`.  How can add this constraint to my table?
Is this Correct?

```
(Year([ContractEnd])<2017) and (Month([ContractEnd])<03) and (Day([ContractEnd])<18)
```

Comment: What type of `ContractEnd`? `DATETIME`?

Comment: No that is not right. The values in your code don't match the date that you stated. And there is no need to break apart a date(time) like that do check.

Comment: The column type is Date.

Comment: Update: Date is 2017-03-18

Answer (score 4):

You can add a constraint like that to an existing table like so:

```
alter table t add constraint chk_ContractEnd_lt_20170319 
  check (ContractEnd<'20170319');
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/FQWFMI88817

```
create table t (
    id int not null identity(1,1)
  , ContractEnd date
  /* at table creation */
  , constraint chk_ContractEnd_lt_20170319 check (ContractEnd<'20170319')
)
alter table t drop constraint chk_ContractEnd_lt_20170319;
/* to existing table */
alter table t add constraint chk_ContractEnd_lt_20170319 
  check (ContractEnd<='20170318');


insert into t values ('20161231')
insert into t values ('20170318')
/* all good */

insert into t values ('20170319')  
/* -- Error, constraint violation */
```

Comment: If the datatype is `datetime` or `datetime2`, then using `ContractEnd < '20170102'` might be necessary.

Comment: @BaconBits That's true.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
[ContractEnd] DATE CHECK ([ContractEnd]  <= '20170318')
```

Comment: I tried what you said, but here is the error:  The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK_Professor". The conflict occurred in database "University", table "dbo.Professor", column 'ContractEnd'.

Comment: @kwram Of course, you should remove previous constraint with name CK_Professor. After that use `alter table Professor add constraint `. do you know how to remove it?

Comment: You are right, but I haven't already set any constraint on this column! I don't have a constraint on this column.

Comment: @kwram no, you have according to the error message. Check `SELECT * FROM sys.check_constraints WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'CK_Professor') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'Professor')`